# Tub gurgles when toilet is flushed

Tags: plumbing

We had the sewer line cleaned out. And my husband got up on the roof to look at the vent, but he said its too hard to see clear down in the vent. It goes too far.

Answer (score 1):

Gurgling drains are usually caused by obstructions in the venting system. The gurgling sound is caused by air being forced through water in your drain trap.

Follow this link for more info:

https://www.tradewindsimports.com/blog/troubleshooting-gurgling-drains/